# Spinners placed at the bottom of an interface are rendered above the user's device buttons

Tags: android, spinner

Does anyone have any idea why it's doing this? I'm making a custom Toolbar of which I put at the bottom of the UI. In that custom toolbar is a Spinner. The problem is, if I put the spinner at the bottom of the screen, the Spinner's menu is render above the whole device UI!

Is there some way to anchor the Spinner's position so that it can only be in the window? How do I fix this?

EDIT: No matter what view I put the Spinner at the bottom of, the bounds are still off.

Here's a picture of the screen with the menu up: [image]

And with the menu not up, so you can see the spinner:  [image]

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/editor_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/editor_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editor_toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editor_toolbar_bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom|right">

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/editor_toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editor_color_chooser_button"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/rgb_color_wheel_selector"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/onepixelborder"
            android:padding="1dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/editor_color_preset_button"
                android:clickable="true">


            </FrameLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:entries="@array/giant_array"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    </Spinner>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```